# Rails 3.1 assets precompile questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

Right now, every time I am changing something in the assets, I have to delete the assets folder from the public directory and then run rake assets:precompile to take effect.

Is this something right or wrong so I should put it in a capistrano task to do it automatically?

For some reason, it doesn't compile automatically the assets in production and it throws errors if I don't do the above (or it doesn't take effect the changes if there is the files already). Is there something I should put in the environments/production.rb?

Also I don't understand what the following code in the production.rb does:

```
  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true
```

I tried false and true but I didn't understand the difference.

I'm a bit confused as at how it should work the workflow in production, if what I am doing is right and about the settings for the assets in production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Capistrano has built-in support for precompiling assets during deployment. Just add this line to your `deploy.rb` file:

```
load "deploy/assets"
```